# Does Peter Pan have the fountain of youth?

Tags: mythology, immortality, peter-pan

We all know that Peter Pan makes his home in the land where you'll never grow up. However, he probably didn't start there, and he likely won't end there. 
In the sixteenth and seventeenth centuries, in the Caribbean, the Spanish believed that there was an island that had the fountain of youth.
Is it coincidental, that there are both pirates and Indians on an island where kids never age?
What I want to know is: Is it possible that the legend of the fountain of youth, could have inspired the story of Peter Pan.

Comment: Loosely not. The central theme of J. M. Barrie's Peter Pan is focused on remaining young to avoid the loss experienced during adulthood. I believe the author was very moved by a recent death. If I can find references I'll try to answer later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **The Spark Behind Peter Pan:**

> Barrie was the author of Peter Pan, but he credited five boys with
>   inspiring the tale: George, John (Jack), Peter, Michael and Nicholas
>   (Nico) Llewelyn Davies. [(Source)](http://www.biography.com/news/peter-pan-jm-barrie-facts-biography)

[image]

[<sup>Michael Llewelyn Davies as Peter Pan, 1906. (Photo: Wikimedia Commons)</sup>](http://www.biography.com/news/peter-pan-jm-barrie-facts-biography)

[This is also a good read](http://www.express.co.uk/comment/expresscomment/327334/Tragedy-that-inspired-creation-of-Peter-Pan) about the tragedy that inspired creation of Peter Pan.

### Water of Life:

From the [**Early Accounts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_of_Youth#Early_accounts) heading in **Wikipedia**:

> A story of the **"Water of Life"** appears in the Eastern versions of the
>   **Alexander** romance, which describes **Alexander the Great** and his servant
>   crossing the *Land of Darkness* to find the restorative spring. These earlier accounts inspired the popular medieval fantasy *The Travels of Sir John Mandeville*, which also mentions the Fountain of Youth as located at the foot of a mountain outside Polombe (modern Kollam) in India. [<sup>(Source)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_of_Youth#Early_accounts)

However, the legend became particularly prominent in the sixteenth century when it became attached to the Spanish explorer ***Juan Ponce de León.***